# What is the json output having this code?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I was given this code to implement so that i could pass it on an API. The problem is that the code that I was handed as an example was not written in PHP. I'm not even sure what programming language this is.

So this is the code:

```
if (check.Comps == null)
   check.Comps = new Dictionary<decimal, CComp>();

check.Comps.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(Settings.CustomDiscount_CompID), new CComp()
{
     CompID = Settings.CustomDiscount_CompID,
     Amount = Math.Round(amount, 3),
     Name = compName
});
```

Now my problem on that code is that I don't know what the json output would be when that code is executed.

I tried guessing it and I think this is the result:

```
[Comps] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CComp] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [CompID] => 10
                    [Name] => 50% discount
                    [Amount] => 30
                )

        )
```

According to the person that I talked to, it is wrong. Now that's where my problem is. Can someone tell me what the json output if that code is executed.

Apologies if I don't explain it properly. Let me know if there's something unclear and I will answer it properly.
Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Who is this cryptic master of the bytes that hands down mystery code in an unknown language?

Comment: Looks like it's written in C#, given the naming convention

Comment: @mwieczorek - i think so too. I heard it was written in C#, but not sure. I just wanted to know what would be the output if that code would be executed.

Comment: I'm guessing your guess is fairly close, since Comp is adding a CComp object with the fields CompId, Name and Amount.

Answer (score 0):

I have to write an answer to format correctly, but the JSON would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "CompId": 10,
    "Name": "50% Discount",
    "Amount": 30
  }
]
```

If the top-level Object has a key (decimal in this case):

```
{
  "3.14159": {
    "CompId": 10,
    "Name": "50% Discount",
    "Amount": 30
  }
}
```

Note that even though the key for each is a decimal, JSON keys must be a string. You'll have to cast to an float or double if you need to use it as such. Of course in PHP, you don't have to cast, but it's good practice.

Comment: Thanks for that. How about the Comps and the CComp keys?

Comment: Check the answer by Chester Cobus - seems he knows more about C# and its output.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a C# Dictionary object being used, the JSON would look something like this:

```
[
  {
     "Key": 10.00,
     "Value": {
                "CompId": 10,
                "Name": "50% Discount",
                "Amount": 30 
             }
  }
]
```